# enviar ficheros al correo con php

Tags: php, html

tengo un formulario donde todos los datos que tu insertas se envían a un correo.
He añadido un apartado para que se puedan subir imágenes ect.. Pero cuando se envía, las imágenes no se envían, me sale lo siguiente en el correo:

```
Imagenes: Array.
```

Este mi html

```
<label for="file-es" role="button">Seleccionar Archivos</label>
                <input id="file-es" name="file_es[]" type="file" multiple>
                <SMALL class="form-text text-muted">Sube aqui las imagenes para que podamos verlas.Maximo de 5.</SMAL>
                <div class="container-contact100-form-btn">
```

y el php es el siguente:

```
<?php

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$portal = $_POST['portal'];
$piso = $_POST['piso'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$incidencia = $_POST['incidencia'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$file_es[] = $_POST['file_es'];


$to = "correo@gmail.com";
$email_subject ="Incidencia : ". $incidencia .".";
$email_body ="Hola esto es un correo generado con una web\n\nNombre: ".$first_name."\nApellido: ".$last_name."\nPortal: ".$portal."\nPiso: ".$piso."\nEmail: ".$email."\nTelefono: ".$phone."\nIncidencia: ".$incidencia."\nMensaje: ".$message."\nImagenes: ".$file_es.".";
$headers = "From: $email \r\n";

  mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
  header("Location: index.html");
?>
```

Comment: Tienes varios problemas en el código. El más grave es el uso del nombre de campo HTML `file_es[]` que es erróneamente leído en `$file_es[]` en vez de iterar por cada valor de `$_FILES`. Por otro lado, la función `mail` te proporciona una interfaz de envío de correos MUY básica. Puedes enviar archivos con ella, pero te será más fácil hacerlo haciendo uso de una biblioteca de funciones o una clase bien definida, documentada y versátil como es [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Answer (score 0):

En tu formulario, el `input` con el que permites al usuario adjuntar imágenes, es un arreglo (`array`). Luego, en la recepción PHP de los datos del formulario, recibes los datos desde el arreglo `$_POST`, cuando debiera ser desde `$_FILES`. Por lo demás, agregar la variable en una cadena de texto (lo que haces al concatenarla en el `body` del email) te devuelve lo que efectivamente recibiste: un arreglo (`Array()`). Te sugiero hacer el cambio que te digo (`$_FILES` en vez de `$_POST`), y que si vas adjuntar las imágenes como archivos, investigues cómo se puede lograr usando `mail()` de PHP (que es el método que estás usando).

> Por cierto, en HTML es necesario aplicar los corchetes al `name` del campo de formulario, pero una vez en PHP, ya no necesitas anotarlas. PHP entiende que si el nombre trae corchetes, se trata de un arreglo, y lo recibe como tal. En ese caso, cuando recibas el arreglo de archivos, basta con `$file_es = $_FILES["file_es"]`. Te sugiero hagas un `print_r($_POST)` y `print_r($_FILES)` al recibir los datos, para saber qué recibiste efectivamente, y *cómo*.

Comment: Si esta respuesta no proporciona una solución a la pregunta deberías haberla puesto como comentario.